# Storing heavy weight on first floor

Tags: storage, drywall

I am renovating my house. I've come to the drywall stage. I would require around 40 sheets of sheetrock to be hung.

Each sheet is 58.8 lb and I'll be buying them together. I'm planning to store them by stacking them on four 2x4's in my living room (on the first floor) , which has a hard-wood floor. That's a total weight of 2352 lbs. Is this safe? Would there be any damage caused by this ?

Comment: Lay the 2x4s perpendicular to the floor joists. To answer this question, someone would probably want to know what the span is and the type/size of the joists. IMO, one 20" stack of drywall is pushing it; make two (as close to a supporting wall as possible). I also prefer them stacked vertically against a wall, perpendicular to the joists -you don't want to point load the middle of the floor. And unless you're getting it delivered, make two trips to the store; your vehicle prob won't like a ton of stuff in it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building code requirements normally require a minimum of around 30-40 pounds per square foot of live loading capacity for standard residential floors. Assuming they are stacked and laid flat (and the floor was built to code), a 4' by 8' section of floor should be designed bear somewhere between roughly 1000 to 1300 lbs of live loading.  Note that this is both the minimum and the average for a uniformly distributed load, so the bearing capacity along the walls will typically be substantially high.

That said - if you have the space, divide it into multiple stacks.  2352 lbs. comes out to 73.5 pounds per square foot. I'll usually stack them up standing against the walls in the rooms they'll be installed in.  Less carrying sheets around when you're hanging it, and unless the room is enormous you don't end up with huge piles anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the pros do not lay the drywall on the floor, it is leaned up against various walls so the cutting to size is done right there. The sheets are easy to finish standing to score and break backwards to finish scoring the other side. A large T square will be really handy here, it will really speed up cutting.

I strongly recommend using a bearing wall to stand the drywall against. If it is laid on the floor, it usually get walked on, corners and edges will get damaged. making the taping job a bit more difficult, or making more cutting needed. For the amount of drywall you have, use 2 walls to stack the drywall, arrange it so those will be the last 2 walls that need to be done. Usually how daylight comes into a room is a consideration here.

When bearing walls are used to lay the drywall against, the carrying capacity is greatly increased over laying it on the floor where the center of the floor carries the load. This would overload the span unless you make smaller piles, more piles to walk on.